# How can my information be stolen if I hide sensitive data inside a PHP file?

Tags: php, security, plaintext

Assume we have a PHP file with sensitive data stored in a VDS like this:

```
<?php /* hidden.php */
      $hidden = "Sensitive data and stuff";
?>
```

And it is read by another file by simply including it:

```
<?php /* easily_accessible.php */
      require("hidden.php");
      if ($password_matches) echo ($hidden);
?>
```

I know in theory that storing data in plain text is poor practice, but how will someone steal my data in this situation?

Besides, are cases when PHP files are displayed as plain files, common with modern server software?

Comment: unless they have direct access to the server you are most likely safe, but if you moved hidden.php outside of web root you protect your self from the unlikely issue of your web server starting to server php files as pain text due to misconfiguration or just 'breaking'

Comment: 1. A misconfigured webserver could show your PHP files as plain text. 2. Anybody with access to your VDS could, of course, read the file. 3. You might inadvertently use `$hidden` in a way you don't expect, and output it to the client. 4. Or you might have left visual error reporting on and that shows the content of `$hidden`. In short: A lot of ways, but normally it shouldn't happen. Best to follow what tim said.

Comment: In short, there is no **direct** access to data stored in a PHP. But if someone finds a way to upload and execute their own PHP file or they gain SSH access to the server, they will be able to view that information. The most common way this happens is via the first method. Which typically happens when 2 or more libraries interact badly or you make a mistake with a file upload script.

Comment: More often than not, these kinds of best practices come from someone learning their mistake "the hard way." The question you should now ask yourself is, "are you going to learn from someone else's mistake or learn it on your own the hard way?"

Comment: @NicholasSummers, I see your point. Thank you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I see, there are a few ways. Thanks!